# Fetch a large chunk of data with TaskQueue

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'd like to **fetch a large file** from an url, but it always raises a *DeadLineExceededError*, although I have tried with a *TaskQueue* and put *deadline=600* to [fetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html).
The problem comes from the fetch, so *Backends* cannot help here : even if i'd launched a backend with a TaskQueue, i'd had [24h to return](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Billing_Quotas_and_Limits), but there 'd be still the limit of 10 min with the fetch, ya ?

Is there a way to fetch from a particular offset of file to an other offset ? So could I split the fetch and after put all parts together ?

Any ideas ?

Actually the file to fetch is not really large : between 15 and 30 MB, but the server is likely overwhelmingly slow and constantly fired ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server supports it, you can supply the [HTTP Range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) to specify a subset of the file that you want to fetch. If the content is being served statically, the server will probably respect range requests; if it's dynamic, it depends on whether the author of the code that generates the response allowed for them.